# Retrieve object with two different attributes in ASP.NET REST-API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a REST API in ASP.NET to CRUD persons. The Person class looks like this:

```cs
class Person
{
    private int id;
    private string name;
    private int age;
    private string email;
}
```

I can already retrieve a person by `id` using the following route:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("person/{personId}")]
public IActionResult Person(int personId)
{
    // This code doesn't matter
    var person = _personManager.Get(personId);
    if (person is null) return NotFound("Person not found");
            
    return Ok(person.ToDto());
}
```

But the problem is that I also want to retrieve a person by it's e-mail. How would I do that? Is this an option?

```cs
// Could this work?
[HttpGet]
[Route("person/email/{personEmail}")]
public IActionResult Person(string email)
{
    // This code doesn't matter
    var person = _personManager.GetByMail(personEmail);
    if (person is null) return NotFound("Person not found");
            
    return Ok(person.ToDto());
}
```

Or is there a better way to do this? The current route `[Route("person/{personId}")]` can't be altered though because it's already used a lot.

Thanks.

Comment: Why won't it work? also, make sure the parameter name and parameter handle in the `Route` attribute match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
[Route("person/{id}")]
[Route("personById/{id}")]
public IActionResult GetPersonById(int id)
{
    // This code doesn't matter
    var person = _personManager.Get(id);
    if (person is null) return NotFound("Person not found");
            
    return Ok(person.ToDto());
}

[Route("personByEmail/{email}")]
public IActionResult GetPersonByEmail(string email)
{
    // This code doesn't matter
    var person = _personManager.GetByMail(personEmail);
    if (person is null) return NotFound("Person not found");
            
    return Ok(person.ToDto());
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the route `[Route("person/{id}")]` is used on a lot of places. We can't just alter it.

Comment: @O'Niel  No problem. I changed it for consistency. You can leave this route as it is.